# Using a grid code to visualize habitat values

Tags: polygon, visualisation, esri-grid-format, habitat-modeling, wildlife-ecology

I am working on wildlife and agriculture data in a region where I am attempting to layer the different types of habitat to show the total value of a parcel. For example, I have layers for endangered species habitat, migration corridors, and winter range and have scored each of these differently depending on the value they represent. If a parcel has endangered species habitat it scores as 11, migration corridors score an 8, and winter range scores a 5. I have taken these habitat layers and overlaid a grid layer for each of them but this process is new to me so I am wondering how I should display the values to then result in a map that shows the total value of a parcel. If a parcel has all three habitat types it should score a 24.
I am using ArcMap 10.8.1 and working with polygon data.

How do I get a map with the sums of the habitat types using a grid? And do these values go in the grid code in the attribute table?

Comment: How is your data stored - polygons or rasters? And what software are you using? Can you please edit your question to include these details - that will help others give a more useful answer.

Comment: Thank you @ycartwhelen I have edited the question to include this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your question is still a little confusing.  You use the word *grid*, which leads me to believe that you are actually working with raster data.  I may be wrong, but will answer with the raster assumption:

With the *Spatial Analyst* extension, you have a couple of choices to summarize overlapping raster grids:

1. The **Plus** tool will sum, cell-by-cell, the values of two overlapping raster grids.
2. With the **Raster Calculator** tool, multiple overlapping raster grids can be summed in one step, in the form of *raster_grid_1 + raster_grid_2 + raster_grid_3*...

In either case, the summed value will  be found in the output raster grid's field *value*.

Note, however, that the field *value* is only presented in an attribute table if the output raster grid has a pixel type of *integer* (if an integer raster grid does not have an attribute table, one can be created with the **Build Raster Attribute Table** tool).  Attribute tables are unavailable if the pixel type is *floating point*.  You can convert a floating point raster to integer with the Spatial Analyst tool **Int**.

Finally, you used the phrase "grid code": If a raster is converted to a vector format (say with the *Raster to Polygon* tool), the input raster's value will be contained in the vector output field *gridcode* (that was a mouthfull!).  If you come across a vector layer that contains the field *gridcode*, that's evidence that the layer had previously existed in raster format.